# List is replacing all old values with the recent one

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I'm facing a weird problem that I did not find for it any explanation, I'll comment in code as follows:

```
     final List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

        Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
//for example payss ArrayList contains `A,B,C,D,E,F,G`
        for (int i=0;i<payss.size();i++){

        Bitmap contact_pic=pays_drapeaux.get(i);   
        drawable=new BitmapDrawable(contact_pic); 
        map.put("pays", payss.get(i).getNom());
        Log.i("PAYS",payss.get(i).getNom()); //here it shows correctly the values one by one
        map.put("drapeau",drawable);

        list.add(map);

       }
  //here want to show what the list contains after setting it above
    for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
    Log.i("VALUES",list.get(i).values().toString()); //but here it shows G,G,G,G,G,G,G
        }
```

As you can see i have at the end a `list` variable with all its values the recent `payss` value (G). Any idea why i'm facing that problem.
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use only one `Map` object and add it several times to the list. In the first loop the entries are always overwritten (since there is only one map). So clearly just the last values survive.

Comment: You have reason, I just detected the problem when you're writing it :D. I'll accept your answer though ;).

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
```

Write above line in for loop. Its very silly mistake ;) :)

Comment: A mistaked that kept me wake up for hours :( !

Comment: Happens... Now it wont happen again. cz nw u hv come across of it. :)

Answer (score 1):

you must create new map in for loop,

```
for (int i=0;i<payss.size();i++){

        map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        Bitmap contact_pic=pays_drapeaux.get(i);   
        drawable=new BitmapDrawable(contact_pic); 
        map.put("pays", payss.get(i).getNom());
        Log.i("PAYS",payss.get(i).getNom()); //here it shows correctly the values one by one
        map.put("drapeau",drawable);

        list.add(map);

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Last night I did not found the solution, but this morning i'm refreshed :D. Here is the solution:
I have to create a Map in every for loop.

```
for (int i=0;i<payss.size();i++){
                Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();

                Bitmap contact_pic=pays_drapeaux.get(i);   
                drawable=new BitmapDrawable(contact_pic); 
                 map.put("pays", payss.get(i).getNom());
                 map.put("drapeau",drawable);
                Log.i("PAYS",payss.get(i).getNom());

                 list.add(map);
}
```